# How does magento figure out to apply the default limit

Tags: php, magento, collections

i've created a custom collection to display in the catalog which lists all newly added items

now i want to fix up the page limit for this new collection to be not be 60 items per page as it is for the rest of the catalog but all, in other words i want to do this

- If the customer goes strait to the new items collection it will display all
- if the customer goes to another category from new items the default 60 items per page is used
- when the customer returns to the new items collection the items per page limit will be set to 60

now i can forcefully get this collection to display all items and when you go to a category your items per page limiter is set to 60 but when you go back to the new items collection it goes back to displaying all items

the only thing i can think of is seeing if the the default items per page limit has been applied yet, how do i check this

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Magento admin then navigate to Catalog > Frontend > "Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values". You can change the values here to change your default.

Also another way is to edit `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalog.xml` near line number 85 but the above should work generally.

Comment: i know about this, i have it set to 60, what i'm asking is how Magento knows when to apply this limit so i can see if i need to force the all filter on or if i can just get what is set for the user already